# how to use Open flash chart (or any library) in flex 3 project?

Tags: flash, flex3, open-flash-chart

I want to use Open Flash Chart in Flex3/AS3 project?

I mean,
How Can I use Open-flash-chart in Flex application client side.. ??? (I use FlashDevelop)

Can i do that by just adding .swf file?? If yes? then where to add? I am not using FlexBuilder, I am using FlashDevelop OR Command line for compiling..

Or I have to add .swc file.. ??? If yes, then how to generate one for open flash chart..???

Cheers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bit complicated than you thing to just add in flex project as Open Flash Chart is not meant to develop for integration in flex. I find a wonderful conversion in here [Open Flash Chart 2 as a Flex SWC component with source code](http://blog.webasp.com.au/2009/06/open-flash-chart-2-kvasir-as-a-flex-swc-component-source-code/)

Open Flash Chart 2 is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I make a new SWC base on WebASP's effort, and fixed some issue I met, include the pie tooltip issue,

You can refer my blog post http://www.smithfox.com/?e=87 for deatil

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, libraries are added by referencing either more code or a SWC.  SWFs are typically used to load whole applications.  The story gets more complicated if one begins to involve [Runtime Share Libraries](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_02.html#220675), but that seems beyond what you need to get started.

[Using the command line, adding a swc based library](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_19.html#158337) is accomplished by modifying the library-path option.